# Too much debugging output to webrick?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm in the middle of trying to upgrade a rails project from rails 2.0.2 to rails 2.3.5

In doing so, I've noticed a change that is driving me nuts. It seems that now by default, any queries that are run by the application get logged to the webrick console (I'm working in Eclipse/Aptana). It used to be that webrick would only show requests for pages/images, etc and now its clouded with tons and tons of junk in the form of every query ever run! There must be a way to turn this off, or modify this behavior? Anyone know how?

Comment: Mongrel's the default for script/server now. Are you sure you're running Webrick?

Comment: Yeah, I created a webrick server in eclipse/aptana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your config/environments/development.rb file update the log level:

```
config.log_level = :info
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER points to STDOUT or something.